# Unable to get document certify level using iText7

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I am using iText for PDF manipulation. In my scenario I am getting the Certify Policy applied on the specific document but iText always returns 0 in any document case.
I am using the following code snippet:

```
PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(_pdfReader, outputStream, new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());
int certificationLevel = pdfSigner.GetCertificationLevel();
```

The document is attached on the following link for reference:

https://1drv.ms/b/s!AvIgyv7xAxxoig9eXND6b14wJGtK?e=A3eM1c

Answer (score 1):

`PdfSigner.GetCertificationLevel()` does **not** return the certification level *implied by existing signatures* as you assume.

Instead it returns the certification level of the signature *this PdfSigner will create*.

As you have not yet called `PdfSigner.SetCertificationLevel()`, the default level 0 (`NOT_CERTIFIED`, a mere approval signature) is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there any way to get the certification level implied by existing signature?

Comment: @MuddassirAwan [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58418033/1729265) outputs the relevant Modification Detection and Prevention information.