# Document field locking using iText7

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext7

I have written a code to lock fields in the document using iText7, the fields are locked in the final document but when left signature panel is opened in Adobe, there is no information regarding field locking is present there.

My code snippet is as follows:

```
        PdfSigFieldLock pdfSigFieldLock = new PdfSigFieldLock();
        pdfSigFieldLock.SetDocumentPermissions(PdfSigFieldLock.LockPermissions.NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
        string[] fieldToLock = new string[]{ fieldName };
        pdfSigFieldLock.SetFieldLock(PdfSigFieldLock.LockAction.ALL, fieldToLock);
        pdfSigner.SetFieldLockDict(pdfSigFieldLock);
```

Document fields are locked but no information regarding document fields locking is shown in signature panel. (expected result shown in image)

[image]

Comment: Can you share full code, seems like issue with the keyword `Using`.

Comment: @Manjuboyz
I am using 2-step signing approach, I am afraid that it is not possible to share the full code.
As far as I Using keyword is concerned, I could not get the point. Apparently I am not applying this keyword in the code block.

Comment: Check if this fixes your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58397100/itext7-c-sharp-check-pdf-was-locked-after-signature

Comment: @Manjuboyz this question is about the signing process, not about the process of analyzing signature properties.

Comment: @Manjuboyz
The link you have shared is for checking what lock permission is applied to the document.
My scenario is to apply document lock to the pdf which I have already implemented but when open locked document in Adobe, there is no information shown in the left signature panel about the document lock property.

Comment: @mkl
Any update on this scenario?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try and remove the **Fields** from the **Lock** dictionary:

```
PdfSigFieldLock pdfSigFieldLock = new PdfSigFieldLock();
pdfSigFieldLock.SetDocumentPermissions(PdfSigFieldLock.LockPermissions.NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
string[] fieldToLock = new string[]{ fieldName };
pdfSigFieldLock.SetFieldLock(PdfSigFieldLock.LockAction.ALL, fieldToLock);
pdfSigFieldLock.GetPdfObject().Remove(PdfName.Fields); // <<<<
pdfSigner.SetFieldLockDict(pdfSigFieldLock);
```

In my tests I did get the desired output [image: Document locked by SH_SIGNATURE_417868] with that change.

Some backgrounds:

That **Fields** entry is specified as *Required if the value of **Action** is Include or Exclude* (ISO 32000-1, Table 233 – Entries in a signature field lock dictionary). In case of the action **All** as in your case, therefore, it is *neither* required *nor* optional. Furthermore, it does not make sense in that case either because *all* fields shall be locked anyways. Adobe Reader, therefore, apparently considers a signature field lock dictionary with a **Fields** entry for an **All** action incorrect. (Well, probably it would accept that entry if all field names of the document are contained, I did not check all possible contents...)

The iText 7 class `PdfSigFieldLock` unfortunately currently automatically creates such a **Fields**, so you have to remove it..

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have implemented this and got the desired results.However I have also implemented another solution prior to your answer and also got the results. That solution is in my answer to this question.
Regards

Comment: Yes. Essentially the problem is that `SetFieldLock` adds an inappropriate **Fields** entry. My solution removes that entry afterwards, your solution does not use `SetFieldLock` to start with but sets the actually needed entries itself. The result is the same either way.

Answer (score 1):

The above scenario can be achieved by manually add values to the PdfSigFieldLock Dictionary.
Here is the code snippet:

```
        PdfDictionary lockDictionary = new PdfDictionary();
        lockDictionary.Put(PdfName.Action, new PdfName("All"));
        lockDictionary.Put(PdfName.P, new PdfNumber(1));

        PdfSigFieldLock pdfSigFieldLock = new PdfSigFieldLock(lockDictionary);
        pdfSigner.SetFieldLockDict(pdfSigFieldLock);
```